# add to cart button is not working

Tags: magento-1.7, php, bundled-product

I have a custom module which does same function of product view page. I am using this module in order to show my bundle products. i have created a fully functional module for this.

I have loaded the product successfully and displayed products name,description, different options in my page. However my add to cart button is not working.

I am loading my product like this

```
<?php
/*getInternationalPlans() is a custom function which filter out bundle products that 
  satisfy certain conditions. there may be more than one bundle products for this   
  function
 */
$_product=$this->getInternationalPlans($custom_select_business);                                    
foreach ( $_product as $product ){
$plan_array [] = $product->getId ();
}

?>
<?php
 /*it unregisters the product  */
  Mage::unregister ( 'product' );
  Mage::register('international_product',$plan_array[0]);// i need only the first product                       
/*  loading the current product*/  
  $_product=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($plan_array[0]);
 /*registering the current product*/
 Mage::register('product', $_product); // add the product object in the registry                    
 $block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View'); // Instantiate the product view block

?>
```

but in default product view page prdoucts are loading using getProduct() method.
my form is like this... which is exactly same as that of default one

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
 id="product_addtocart_form"
  <?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"
 <?php endif; ?>> 
       /*all options are showing here*/
      /*...................................*/
         $buttonTitle = $this->__('Order Now');
         <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="international_btn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
 </form>
```

However the action part of form is blank, after I load this code. when I click on the button, it loads the same page again and during consoling it says that `'productId is not defined'`. So I have checked `'productAddToCartForm '` definition and found out that it uses `'productId'` in its definition. How can I set `'prdouctId'`  in my page? why form action field is empty?

how can make my order now button work perfectly?

Please help me...

Comment: So `ce-1.7` or `ce-1.8`?

Comment: this is ce-1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the standard layout there is a hidden field that sets this in the product view template (/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml):

```
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
```

I would suggest with your code you could simple add this hidden field after the form is opened.

The form gets the action from calling `$this->getSubmitUrl($_product)`. If you look into the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` you will see the default way of getting this. The easiest option would be to make sure that your block extends this class or another block that extends it (e.g. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`). Something like the following would be enough.

```
class Your_Catalog_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
```

Comment: i have added following code.. but it didnt work. loads the same page again. why action field of form is empty?

Comment: Oh sorry I miss read your question. What block are you using to show this form? As you will need the action from the block abstract Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

Comment: i copied the form element definition from view.phtml file and pasted it in my custom view.phtml page. since i have loaded the prdouct to the variable $_product, i assumed that, it may work like standard form element definition. howewver it didnt worked. please note that, i am not using any of standard blocks in my custom module.

Comment: see my edit about the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` as this holds the getSubmitUrl code

Comment: what should i do in order to get this action from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract?

Comment: Your block needs to extend this or another block that extends the abstract.

Comment: my block now extends Mage_Core_Block_Template now. can i use Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract instead of that?

Comment: Yes as that extends Mage_Core_Block_Template also

Comment: thanks. now the form field is not empty. now again the button is not working. the problem is ProductId is not set. how can i set it in my view.phtml page?

Comment: hi @programmer_rkt , thanks for this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/slideshow-is-not-working-in-magento-site?noredirect=1#comment48401_35348 , now its resolved , problem by some extension.

Answer (score 2):

You does not add this Block in Form

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

or you can also add this in form

```
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php Mage::getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()?>" name="form_key">
```